# possible to set the browser zoom level to 100% when opening a single image?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, browser

I have a Wordpress site and need to create a gallery of sorts. The problem is, most of the images I want to show (which are website comps) are too long for my screen (27" imac), and when the user clicks the thumbnail, the image opens up zoomed *out* so the entire image fits within the window. I know the user can click on the image to zoom in to 100%, but is there a way to override the browser default and set it to open at 100% automatically? I'd love to find a css fix for this!

Here's an example image: http://openbox9.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/9marks_journal_landing_rd3.jpg

Comment: Cant you use make a HTML page and insert the image? It will not try to fit... If you are hardlinking to a JPEG, though, you cant override behaviour as you are not serving anything but image data.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is using the CSS `zoom` property. From what I know, the zoom property is supported in most modern browsers and should do what you need. Here is an example:

```css
/*CSS*/

#image {
   zoom: 100%;
}

<!--HTML-->
```

```html
<image src="http://openbox9.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/9marks_journal_landing_rd3.jpg" id="image">
```